# Mixin of invariant type - type mismatch found some other

Tags: scala

In the code below, I get the above error on the "problem" line below. My question is whether it is possible to have a variable declaration for z such that it could be assigned either of x or y. My work-around is the consumeProduce method which I don't really want. Thanks for input!

```
package org.rest.rest

trait Common

case class A() extends Common
case class B() extends Common

trait Producer[T <: Common] {
  def produce(name: String): T = ???
}

trait Consumer[T <: Common] {
  def consume(t: T): Unit = { }
}

class ProducerConsumer[T <: Common] extends Producer[T] with Consumer[T]    {
 // don't really want this method
  def consumeProduce(name: String): Unit =
    consume(produce(name))
}

object DemoMI {

  val x = new ProducerConsumer[A]
  x.consume(x.produce("abc"))
  val y = new ProducerConsumer[B]
  y.consume(y.produce("abc"))
  val z: ProducerConsumer[_] = x // what type declaration for z is possible here?
  z.consume(z.produce("abc")) // problem
  z.consumeProduce("abc") // works

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried using covariance and contravariance some how?

Comment: @pedrofurla, the error is in the question title.

Comment: @Ben Reich, yes I did try covariance, but in my initial approach it raises problems elsewhere (at the call sites),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Scala compile does not know that `z.consume` takes what `z.produce` produces.

You can use abstract type members to solve this:

```
trait Producer {
  type T <: Common
  def produce(name: String): T = ???
}

trait Consumer {
  type T <: Common
  def consume(t: T): Unit = { }
}

trait ProducerConsumer extends Producer with Consumer

object DemoMI {
  val x = new ProducerConsumer {
    type T = A
    // definitions of consume and produce
  }

  val z: ProducerConsumer = x

  z.consume(z.produce("abc"))
}
```

Abstract type members give raise to the notion of so-called path-dependent types. In the upper example, `z.produce(...)` has the type `z.T`. `z.consume(...)` on the other hand takes a value of type `z.T`. Although the compiler does not know the concrete type that is involved, it knows that both methods have compatible types and therefore happily compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @gzm0 has the solution. I did try abstract type members but wasn't able to make them behave differently to parameterized traits. A further refinement I was now able to add was to combine the effects thus:

```
  trait ProducerConsumer extends Producer with Consumer 

  abstract class AbstractProducerConsumer[TT <: Common] extends ProducerConsumer {
    type T = TT
  }

  val x = new AbstractProducerConsumer[A] {}
  x.consume(x.produce("abc"))
  val y = new AbstractProducerConsumer[B] {}
  y.consume(y.produce("abc"))
  val z1: ProducerConsumer = x
  z1.consume(z1.produce("abc"))
  val z2: ProducerConsumer = y
  z2.consume(z2.produce("abc"))
```